# How can I prevent the auto scrolling after dragEnter-winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scrollbar

When I drag to `textBox` the `Vertical scrollbar` always moves up
I want to cancel this behavior or to take it back immediately
if you need more infomation please leave a comment

Comment: I think we need more information about what you mean when you say "I scroll to textbox". Are you saying that you are scrolling the box with the mouse scroll wheel? are you adding text and it is autoscrolling? Also, When you say the Veritcal scroll bar moves up, are you trying to also prevent the text from scrolling, or just the scrollbar? are you wanting the text to scroll the opposite way? We need more information about the behavior that you want to change, and what you want it to be. Please be verbose.

Comment: You are right-thank you, I wrote  by mistake scroll instead drag and I didn't understand why nobody answer me

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you're literally dragging text to the TextBox to add to it, whenever a TextBox gets updated it'll do that.  What you can do is create a TextChanged event and tell it to scroll to the end.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```